# Data is not returned via anonymous PIPE if the child is waiting for a key press

Tags: c, pipe, parent-child, wait

Why doesn't PIPE return anything if the parent process is waiting for a key?
On entering a key in the terminal, nothing happens.

If you remove the **SYSTEM** command, then the data comes.

Can you please tell me why the terminal does not redirect the keystroke to the child process?

I would appreciate any hint.

Parent:

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h> 
#include <unistd.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <sys/ioctl.h>
#include <sys/select.h>
#define FIONREAD    0x541B

void write_pipe(int p , char* szBuf)
{
    
    write(p, szBuf, strlen(szBuf));
    
    sleep(1);

}

void read_pipe(int p)
{

    int iTotalBytesAvail;
    
    for (int i = 0; i < 10000 ; i++)
    {
        ioctl(p , FIONREAD, &iTotalBytesAvail);

        if (iTotalBytesAvail)
        {
            char *sBuf = calloc(1 , iTotalBytesAvail+1);
            
            if (sBuf)
            {
                read(p, sBuf, iTotalBytesAvail);
                
                printf("%s", sBuf);

                free(sBuf);
            };

        };
    };

}

int main()
{

    char* sPath = "./addone";

    int stdin_pipe[2];
    int stdout_pipe[2];
    int pid;

    if ((pipe(stdin_pipe)<0) || (pipe(stdout_pipe)<0)) return -1;
    
    fcntl(stdin_pipe[0], F_SETFL, O_NONBLOCK);
    fcntl(stdin_pipe[1], F_SETFL, O_NONBLOCK);
    //fcntl(stdout_pipe[0], F_SETFL, O_NONBLOCK);
    fcntl(stdout_pipe[1], F_SETFL, O_NONBLOCK);

    pid = fork();

    if(pid == 0)
    {
        close(stdin_pipe[0]);
        close(stdout_pipe[1]);
        dup2(stdout_pipe[0], STDIN_FILENO);
        dup2(stdin_pipe[1], STDOUT_FILENO);
        close(stdout_pipe[0]);
        close(stdin_pipe[1]);
        execl(sPath, sPath , NULL);
        //return 0;
    }
    else
    {
        close(stdin_pipe[1]);
        close(stdout_pipe[0]);
    }

    sleep(1);
    while (1)
    {
    read_pipe(stdin_pipe[0]);
    };
}
```

child (addone):

```
#include <unistd.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    printf("AAAA\n");
    system("read -p 'Press Enter to continue...' var");
    printf("BBBB\n");
}
```

Comment: What you replace `system` with?

Comment: Well your main program sets up the child to read input from one of your pipes, but you never write to it from the parent process. How would it receive the "Enter to continue..."?

Comment: Also make it a habit to *always* check what `read` and `write` returns.

Comment: I didn't understand the question. The SYSTEM command in this case is just PAUSE before entering any key.

Comment: **Well your main program sets up the child to read input from one of your pipes, but you never write to it from the parent process. How would it receive the "Enter to continue..."?**

Why is the key pressed in the terminal not being redirected to the child process?

Comment: Because the child process, and its child processes in turn, have their standard input from the pipe, not the terminal.

Comment: Thank you all for your answers. I understood.